# Error with presentViewController - no visible @interface for AppDelegate

Tags: xcode, authentication

I am making a splitview application for ipad and I need to display a different view controller for login purposes. 
I call this in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function in Appdelegate:

```
    LoginViewController *login = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
[info setModalTransitionStyle: UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
[self presentViewController:login animated:YES completion: nil];
```

but I get the error "No visible @interface for AppDelegate declares the selector presentViewController" on the third line.

The view controller I want to display is set to the LoginViewController class.
I have Imported all classes.

I am pretty new to programming and would really appreciate any help!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

What the error message says is that the class `AppDelegate` does not contain a method called `presentViewController`. Indeed, that method belongs to `UIViewController` class.

What you should do depends on how you created your project, whether it uses a navigation controller, a tab bar controller, or a simple view controller.

From your comment, I understand you used the Window-based template (or Empty application) to create your project. In this case, in your `application:didFinishLaunching:` you should have something like this:

```
self.login = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
[self.window addSubview:self.login.view];
```

and also add to your AppDelegate.h the following declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) LoginViewController* login;
```

If this seems not to apply to your case, please, post your definition of `application:didFinishLaunching:`

Comment: This is all I have in my AppDelegate.h:                           `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end`

Comment: I have added the property in Appdelegate.h and this is what I now have in application:didfinishlaunching :                                           `self.login = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window addSubview:self.login.view];

        LoginViewController *login = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
        [info setModalTransitionStyle: UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    
    [self presentViewController:login animated:YES completion: nil];` somehow it is still not working.. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: I assume that your second `login` (the local variable) was meant to be `info` (if not, what is `info setModalTransitionStyle`?); then you should do: `[self.login presentViewController:info animated:YES completion: nil];` -- but you see that this not makes a lot of sense. You present a modal if you already have a view controller on screen and you want to modally display something on top of it; if you don't have anything (like I was supposing in your case), you can simply use `addSubview` and that's it. It is not really useful to display the same login view controller modally on top of itself.